# Can everything which can be done with "while" loops be done with "for" loops and vice versa?

Tags: c, loops

Is it true that, in C, we can do anything using `while` loop which can be done using `for` loop and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: Yup, all loop can achieve same goal with different implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, except for definition of variables inside `for`

```
for (init; cond; incr) { body; }
```

If `body` does not contain a `continue` statement, the `for` statement above is completely equivalent to the `while` loop below.

```
init;
while (cond) {
    body;
    incr;
}
```

---

If you add an extra set of curly braces, even the definition of variables can be converted from `for` to `while`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { printf("%d\n", i); }
```

is the same as

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a for loop can be constructed with a while loop.

```
{   int i = 0;
    while(i < 10){
// statement block without continue.
        ++i;
    }
}
```

and a for loop can replace a while loop trivially by omitting the init and increment sections.

This doesn't mean it's a good idea. They have different semantics.  The for loop is used to iterate over a given set of elements, i.e.

```
for(auto e: collection)...
```

while is used for other non counting iterations.

Comment: your while loop won't be equivalent in the presence of `continue` statements

Comment: @AlanBirtles  Excellent point.

Comment: You seem to have the languages mixed up. The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: @user17732522 When I answered the Q it was tagged both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used vice-versa. But for a code to be more readable, its wise to use the appropriate one.

**while loop usage** : loop until a condition is met. the condition is met due to the actions inside the loop.

**for loop usage** : loop until a condition is met. Here the condition is met be more or less increment/decrement operator present in for loop syntax iteself.